# How can I separate my Jenkins build in a docker container and keep it clean?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins running in a docker container. Now I want to start my builds on docker. But what I see in the log, is that the volume of the workspace is mounted onto the docker container for the build.

Does that mean that all my builds are run in the same workspace folder? That is exactly what I wanted to prevent.

How can I ensure that the git checkout is done in the docker container and that it is removed after running that build?

```
+docker build -t c477d0c74731a417e6e0ba1563a397aad8ab76ee --target builder -f cpp/Dockerfile cpp
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.307MB
...  
Successfully built 4bc8ce7a4ad3
Jenkins seems to be running inside container 11e315121188683c9e1c7e02d5924a7a550324b8f9957f6cae580f80d04359db
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/jobs/Docker-Cpp-Demo/branches/master/workspace --volumes-from 11e315121188683c9e1c7e02d5924a7a550324b8f9957f6cae580f80d04359db
```

I see from this log that `--volumes-from` is mounting the volumes from the Jenkins instance. And that the workspace is in `/var/...`. Does this mean that it is a shared volume and therefore not cleaned up after the build?

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        dockerfile {
            dir 'cpp'
            additionalBuildArgs '--target builder'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                dir('cpp') {
                    sh 'cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install'
                    sh 'cmake --build build --target install'
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'cpp/install/**'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcc:10.2.0 AS builder

# Install cmake
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake
```

Comment: you can customize your workspace by using [ws Jenkins dsl](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#ws-allocate-workspace) 
or clean your workspace in post dsl by using deleteDir(), so that it will clean even if the pipeline checkouts your source code in jenkins default workspace directory.

Comment: But that would still mean that two builds of the same branch cannot run at the same time, since it is sharing workspace. I was hoping that docker solves that issue for me.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario, I mean your build steps? so that I will try to make an example.
If I understand correctly, You want to run the same branch build in 2 different scenarios but you don't want Jenkins to share the workspace? 

Your scenario looks interesting to me and loves to give it a try for a demo.

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel Suppose someone does two commits quite close after another. My Jenkins instance has the capability to run 8 builds in parallel. Therefore it is plausible that two builds on the same branch start at the same time. And they will run in the same workspace. That is something I want to avoid. The builds steps themselves don't matter in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Jenkins ever share the same workspace If concurrent build happens for a job. If no concurrent, it uses the same workspace.
Check my Below example and observation

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node("master") {
    stage('one') {
        sh """
            echo "Hello World - $BUILD_ID" >> file.txt
            sleep 5
            ls -al
            cat file.txt
        """
    }
}
```

[image]

**Workspace in the jenkins_home will look like**
[image]

On the screenshot, you can observe for the same concurrent Job Jenkins use a different workspace folder and the naming convention Jenkins followed was <JOB_NAME>@<CONCURENT_NUMBER>

With Docker build agent, the scenario is the same

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'alpine:latest'
            label 'master'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('one'){
            steps {
                sh """
                    echo "Hello World - $BUILD_ID" >> file.txt
                    sleep 5
                    ls -al
                    cat file.txt
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Build log**

```
docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@tmp:rw,z -e ******** alpine:latest cat

docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@2 -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@2:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@2:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@2@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@2@tmp:rw,z -e ******** alpine:latest cat

ocker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@3 -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@3:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@3:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@3@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/declarative-pipeline@3@tmp:rw,z -e ******** alpine:latest cat
```

**Workspace folder structure**

[image]

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of this. Thanks for the insight. This is going to help me a bunch.